# Open html<video> tag content (having mp4 video!) in new window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-video

### Help me with an example using only html code or with script to display more than 2 mp4 video link to a new window when we click button on first page . And only one html code that performs the job

Comment: what have you tried doing? also write some code so it's easier for others to help. we can't help you if you can't help us clarify.

Comment: You can check this https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: well, what are you trying to do isn't just and `<a href="linkto.mp4" target="_blank">button</a>` ?